# 17.04 can't connect to wifi using TL-WD8200ND v1.1 usb adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Searched all over the place and couldn't find an answer for this.

I have a TP-LINK wireless adapter that i use to connect to my router. When i plug it, Ubuntu recognize it, it shows me the available networks but when i try to connect it fails.
I can connect to WiFi i'm using a different WiFi adapter a borrowed from a friend. It seems the issue is with this specific card.

I already did added

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=o
```

To `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
so again, its working but not for the TL-WD8200ND card.

i tried installing windows drivers with ndiswrapper 1.61 latest version but no change. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GW_Q9izVYBA

The same problem happen in other Ubuntu based distros such as Elementary, Mint. I also tried Ubuntu budgie 16.04 and no luck.

here is a pastebin with all the network information http://paste.ubuntu.com/25174818/

I was wondering is there a workaround/ fix ?

Any help is kindly appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

The correct entry change to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` is:

```
 [device] 
 wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

In other words, not =o but =no. Please change the file, proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Second, you have two possibly conflicting drivers loaded. Let's blacklist one:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8192cu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: The led in the usb device does not turn on now, i can still scan networks but not able to connect. here is the wireless script result again. https://paste.ubuntu.com/25179976/ i would also mention im using a different tp- link wireless adapter TL-WD7200ND which i borrowed from a friend. Btw ndiswrapper windows drivers aren't installed when i tried this, should i install them again?

Comment: Which device are we trying to troubleshoot?? Again, you have conflicting drivers loaded.

Comment: TL-WD8200ND is the device that i want to get it working

Comment: Please remove the 7200ND, reboot and let us see a new wireless script.

Comment: unplugged the 7200ND, plugged the 8200ND, tried to connect to wifi and then i ran the script. https://paste.ubuntu.com/25188179/ , by the way its what i did last time. thanks for your responses

Comment: i reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04, did the above instructions again. fails to connect. here is the script https://paste.ubuntu.com/25208085/ please don't give up on me! Thanks!

Comment: rtl8192cu is not blacklisted because it's loaded. Also, conflicting drivers, namely rt2800usb are loaded, making troubleshooting nearly impossible. Please retrace your steps, remove the Ralink wireless, reboot, run the script and post it. I *cannot* emphasize strongly enough that only rtl8xxxu must be loaded in order to see clearly what is going wrong. Please.

Comment: Finally, i ran the script and only rtl8xxxu is loaded. I'm proving the results before i tried to make a connection with 8200ND https://paste.ubuntu.com/25215401/ and after i tried to connect -> https://paste.ubuntu.com/25215403/ thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: The change I suggested to NetworkManager.conf is not done as shown in the paste. Please retrace your steps and after making the change, reboot and show us a new paste.

Comment: sorry, thought it was relevent to17.04 only. here is the pastebin again before connection https://paste.ubuntu.com/25215657/ and after connection -> https://paste.ubuntu.com/25215658/

Comment: Is the new paste good? can i do something to provide more information?